# problem showing full image using .place() in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, label

I have my code looks something like this, I have to say the program I'm trying to create will have several tabs (8-10) and many widgets inside of them, so I chose to design the graphical interfaz using .place(). I have been trying to show a picture but it doesn't show full, I tried using canvas and label but both showed partly the picture.

this is my code

```
from tkinter import * #GUI
from tkinter import ttk #GUI
from PIL import ImageTk,Image  
root = Tk()

root.title("Example") #Title

####get resolution
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
#### end get resolution
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill="both",expand=1) 


frame.config(width=screen_width,height=screen_height)

tabControl = ttk.Notebook(root)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tabControl.add(tab1, text='Tab 1')
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabControl) 
tabControl.add(tab2, text='Tab 2')

tabControl.place(x=0,y=round(screen_height * .2), 
width=round(screen_width),height=round(screen_height * .9))

frame_one = LabelFrame(tab1, text="Image")
frame_one.place(x=round(screen_width * .6),y=round(screen_height * 
.01),width=round(screen_width * .3),height=round(screen_height * .3))

frame_two = LabelFrame(tab1, text="Image")
frame_two.place(x=round(screen_width * .6),y=round(screen_height * 
.35),width=round(screen_width * .3),height=round(screen_height * .3))

frame_three = LabelFrame(tab1, text="Labels, radios, checkbuttons, 
buttons")
frame_three.place(x=round(screen_width * .01),y=round(screen_height * 
.01),width=round(screen_width * .55),height=round(screen_height * 
.65))

button = Button(tab1,text="Button")
button.place(x=round(screen_width * 0.45), y=round(screen_height * 
.66))

canv = Canvas(tab1)
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.jpg"))  # PIL solution
canv.create_image(0, 0, image=img, anchor=NW)
canv.place(x=round(screen_width * .605),y=round(screen_height * 0.03), 
width=round(screen_width * .29), height=round(screen_height * .28))

canv2 = Canvas(tab1)
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("test.jpg"))  # PIL solution
canv2.create_image(0, 0, image=img2, anchor=NW)
canv2.place(x=round(screen_width * .605),y=round(screen_height * 
0.37), width=round(screen_width * .29), height=round(screen_height * 
.28))

root.mainloop()
```

I hope someone can help me to show the picture in full

Comment: Since you have restricted the size of the canvases in `place(...)`, is the size big enough to show the whole image?

Comment: `place` almost always makes it harder to create a responsive UI than using `pack` or `grid`.

Comment: I know place() makes it harder but I have several of widgets and need to show them in a specific way, that's why I used place. The problem is that I can't resize the picture because user will choose one and show it.

Comment: But you can resize the loaded image to fit into the canvas.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I tried to do it but I couldn't. I'm new in python is my first program

Comment: Example: `img = Image.open('test.jpg')`, then `img.thumbnail((width, height))` where `width` and `height` is the size of the canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have restricted the size of the canvas using `place(...)`, the size of the canvas may not be big enough to show the full image.

You can resize the loaded image to fit into the canvas using `PIL.Image.thumbnail()`:

```
canv = Canvas(frame_one) # put into LabelFrame
canv.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
canv.update() # required to get the real size of canvas
w, h = canv.winfo_width(), canv.winfo_height()
img = Image.open("test.jpg")
img.thumbnail((w, h))
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
canv.create_image(w//2, h//2, image=img, anchor=CENTER)

canv2 = Canvas(frame_two)
canv2.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
canv2.update()
w, h = canv2.winfo_width(), canv.winfo_height()
img2 = Image.open("test.jpg")
img2.thumbnail((w, h))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img2)
canv2.create_image(w//2, h//2, image=img2, anchor=CENTER)
```

Please note that `thumbnail()` will only resize the image if its size is bigger than the given size to the function.